# Why is there a number being inserted into this view?

Tags: 7, views

I've set up a view to show the first image in my gallery, but for some reason it is inserting the number 1 after each image it shows. I can't find anything in my settings that seems obvious, so what is going on here?

Picture of the problem (there should not be anything but the picture in this cell):

[image: 1st gallery item with a "1" after it.]

I've also changed it to show 2 items and the "1" still persists.

Comment: please provide a screenshot of your views settings.

Comment: are you using rewritten field ?